# Using npm start with PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am currently using pm2 to manage my node processes on my VPS. I am running the following command with PM2: `pm2 start npm -- start`. This works fine except for the fact that I can only use it for one process.

I have 2 processes that each use npm start to start it. When I run `pm2 start npm -- start` in the folder of the 2nd process, it does not add it to pm2. Instead it just restarts my first process.

How would I use my 2nd process with pm2?

Comment: Do your services use the same port?

Comment: It is a discord bot @pzaenger